# Is there a way to paste all columns at once

Tags: r

Is there a way to paste all columns at once in a dataframe

```
asd <- data.frame(a = c("A", "B"), b = c(1,2))
```

I need to paste all columns (a and b) and and alter column A as below

```
asd$a <- paste0(asd$a, "_", asd$b)
```

But is there a way to automate because, if a dataframe has many columns (a, b, c and so on).

```
asd <- data.frame(a = c("A", "B"), b = c(1,2), c = c(1,2), x = c(1,2))
```

Expected output (need to combine only a, b and c)

```
asd
      a    b  c  x
1 A_1_1    1  1  1
2 B_2_2    2  2  2
```

we can do it using `asd$a <- paste0(asd$a, "_", asd$b, "_", asd$c)` but looking for some simple approach.

I tried with below function but not working

```
paste_function <- function(df, df_col = c(a, b)){
  for (i in df_col){
    return(substr(paste0(df,'$',df_col,collapse = ",", sep = ",'_'"), 1,nchar(paste0(df,'$',df_col,collapse = ",", sep = ",'_'"))-4))
  }
}

asd$a <- paste_function(asd, df_col = c(a, b, c))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `do.call`

```
asd$a <- do.call(paste, c(asd, sep = '_'))
asd
        a b c d
1 A_1_1_1 1 1 1
2 B_2_2_2 2 2 2
```

---

Other ways include:

```
rlang::exec(paste, !!!asd, sep = '_')
purrr::lift(paste)(asd, sep = '_') # deprecated
purrr::invoke(paste, asd, sep = '_') # deprecated
```

Comment: I do not need column d here

Comment: @Rakshu you can do away with column `d` ie `do.call(paste, c(subset(asd,,-d), sep = '_'))`

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect use case for `unite` function from `tidyr` package:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

asd %>% 
  unite("a", a:x, sep = "_", remove = FALSE)
```

```
       a b c x
1 A_1_1_1 1 1 1
2 B_2_2_2 2 2 2
```